# Google Contact ContactsQuery GData API returning intermittent "500 Internal Sever Error"

Tags: google-contacts-api

Thursday June 21st, 2018 we started receiving reports from users, mostly outside of the United States, that the contact sync using the GDATA Contact API is returning a "500 Internal Sever Error" when requesting contact updates.

This issue is occurring across a number of product releases and I am certain the root issue is not related to any recent code changes on our side.

I am unable to find any information from Google regarding any recent changes or service outages related to the Google Contact API.

I would appreciate if someone at Google can comment on this recent issue to provide some details around the recent issue and if/when the issue will be resolved.

I did have one customer today report the error magically disappeared without any changes on their part.

Here is a stack trace (minus the email address)

```
    Execution of request failed: https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/.../full 
Stack -->    at Google.GData.Client.GDataRequest.Execute()
    at Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute(Int32 retryCounter)
    at Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute(Int32 retryCounter)
    at Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute(Int32 retryCounter)
    at Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute(Int32 retryCounter)
    at Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute(Int32 retryCounter)
    at Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute(Int32 retryCounter)
    at Google.GData.Client.GOAuth2Request.Execute()
    at Google.GData.Client.Service.Query(Uri queryUri, DateTime ifModifiedSince, String etag, Int64& contentLength)
    at Google.GData.Client.Service.Query(FeedQuery feedQuery)
```

`

Comment: 500 is a Google Server error. Is this still occurring?

Comment: Yes, we continue to receive reports of this error. The last one came in about 25 minutes ago and several per hour have been reported since then,

Comment: We are getting these errors too.  We have noticed that it seems to be HttpRequest.UserAgent related.

We make use of Googles GData libraries and it gives us a UserAgent of G-ApplicationName-3.4.18.0/GOAuth2ServiceAccountRequestFactory-CS-Version=2.2.0.28127

It appears that the -CS- part of the UserAgent is causing issues

Comment: Does changing the user agent fix this issue? Do you have an example of a user agent definition that does work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that it was fixed today, as I don't see errors anymore.

Comment: I am also not seeing any new reports of the issue. Would be nice for Google to commend on this issue.